# What is Husserl's "reductionist method"?

Tags: phenomenology, husserl, methodology

In Ideas, Husserl seems pretty convinced that phenomenology is a new science. He says that phenomenology is a *descriptive* science, and having read through Merleau-Ponty's Phenomenology of Perception, I can see that the latter author has taken this definition factually.

But Ideas is an abstruse text, and Husserl mentions many new concepts: the natural standpoint; religious consciousness; and the reductionist method, for example.

While I am given to understand that phenomenology is *not* a science, in the sense in which Husserl implies, I would be interested to understand the ways he came to think this. One thing that would help me, would be to understand better the "reductionist method".

I assume bracketing is involved here. But is there a "bullet-list" type answer to this question? I am a layman.

Comment: The encylopedy https://iep.utm.edu/phen-red/ has intermediate headings which can be used as bullet points for phenomenological reduction. Nevertheless, reading Husserl can be a polarizing enterprise :-)

Comment: Husserl generally had a different idea of what "science" means than the one prevailing today, see his [Philosophy as Rigorous Science](https://www.academia.edu/35010093) and [Gelan's commentary, The Idea of Rigorous Science in Husserl's Phenomenology](https://philarchive.org/archive/GELTIO-2). On *epoché* (phenomenological reduction method) in Ideas see also [SEP, The phenomenological *epoché*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/husserl/#PheEpo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reductionist method, or "phenomenological reduction", can indeed be broken down into "bullet-points." In fact there are two *moments*, where we say "moments" rather than "steps", for in fact the method is carried out almost in a single sweep. The moments are:-

1. Epoche, or "Bracketing". This is a familiar process whereby one suspends one's judgement about the existence of the external world. Attention to the objective reality of things is thereby shifted away towards the subjective experience of those things. Husserl says that we live according to cultural precepts, that we live in a "captivation-in-an-acceptedness", that we take for granted cultural facets of our existence. In bracketing we leave go of this world; but this is not *denial* of the world. We see things in their abstract light.
2. The Reduction Proper. Here we recognise the aforementioned acceptance of the world *as* an acceptance. It is a "radicalised meditation" wherein the 'goal' is to achieve transcendental insight into that which has held us captive. It is a form of "seeing"; the type that may occur in astonishment. It involves human "inwardness" but really involves the entire human "I".

The Reductionist Method is cited as being a physical process, that is meditative, and is purported to be as enlightening once achieved, by practice, performance and maintenance, as a religious conversion, and it is said that the method finally gives us access to the status of being a phenomenologist.

It seems to me personally to be somewhat esoteric, and having practiced it myself, a development of the *cogito* and Platonic form.

Thanks to @Jo Wehler for the link in above comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).